Using Lookup Activity to execute stored procedure using script by passing lookup value
Summary: in ADF pipeline, using lookup to select all the data and passing each row at a time to ForEach activity. Inside ForEach activity, first I have copy data activity where I read value from lookup and pass as source and sink and load data. Next I was to run a stored procedure. Repeat this process till all lookup has been completed.
SELECT [SchemaName]
      ,[TableName]
      ,[SourceFilePath]
      ,[StoredProcedure_1]
FROM [dbo].[ADF_ControlTable]


@item().SchemaName
@item().TableName
@item().SourceFilePath
@item().StoredProcedure_1

Copy Data activity using source and sink with @item() value, I am loading data from file to table (this works as intended).
Next step I want to execute script activity within foreach and execute @item().StoredProcedure_1
This is showing user configuration issue:

must declare scalar variable "@item"



The above error will arise when you gave the ADF dynamic expression in the normal SQL script. If the @item().StoredProcedure_1 is a stored procedure name, and the above error will occur when you give the expression like below.

The above box will execute the SQL query. If you want to give the ADF expression in the query, you need to either use string concatenation or concat() function.
Using String concatenation @{<ADF_expression>}:
Give the query like below:
exec @{item().StoredProcedure_1}


This will execute the script activity as per your requirement.
Or You can also use concat() function. Concat the SQL query and above expression like below. In the query open dynamic expression and give this expression.
@concat('exec ',item().StoredProcedure_1)

